# How to get Team Foundation Service to download nuget packages

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I have a Git based Team Project hosted on Team Foundation Service and to avoid checking in packages into the repository, I have enabled NuGet package restore on the solution. I may have missed a fundamental step in having the hosted build controller source these packages (the project is a standard MVC4 Web Api template) as I get this from the failed build log

```
  Unable to find version '2.0.20715.0' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'.
  Unable to find version '4.0.20710.0' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'.
  etc..
```

It doesn't seem correct to publish these packages to my own nuget feed (myget.org) as they are already available via package manager console, I simple need the TFS hosted controller to fetch them. Does anyone know how I might achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the server have access to the Internet generally? I.e. no proxy that might limit it to certain sites?

Comment: This is all fine from connectivity standpoint - I have done this with a 3rd party product to manage NaaS with TFS (expensive tho)

Comment: Have you checked all the files in, after enabling package restore? Specifically the SLN? I got screwed over once by that. (file, save all in visual studio)

Comment: Just had a look at that, it's all checked in. I have a empty packages folder (except for repositories.config), a packages.config at the project root which lists all the packages.

Comment: It looks like @abatishchev had problems with an MVC4 project in the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899638/build-issue-when-using-package-restore-in-team-foundation-service

Comment: Many thanks for your help,  in the end I pushed each of the problem packages manually to the nuget feed which got it compiling. So I sort of worked around the issue rather than finding out why their build controller couldnt download them directly.

Comment: You're welcome. If nothing else, take heart that it seems like [it's a pretty common problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/1fc22ffb-1cdb-41e4-a320-8eca8cfb342d/) and probably not your fault.